# Runtime Crash in C++ when built on Mavericks GM

Tags: c++, xcode, osx-mavericks

I'm running on the Mavericks GM with Xcode 5.0.1 GM.  The OS X SDK used to compile against doesn't seem to matter.  I've tried recompiling my company's software with both the 10.8 and 10.9 SDKs.  I get the same result compiling for Debug and Release.  Oddly enough, if I compile on 10.7 or 10.8 and bring the binaries over to a 10.9 machine, everything works fine.

The software I work on is written in C++ and runs about 600K lines of code.  Nothing in our codebase uses lbxpc directly.  Some of the biggest external libraries used:

- Qt 4.8.5
- Boost 1.49.0
- OpenCL (dynamically loaded at runtime)
- OpenEXR
- Growl 1.2.1

Whenever the crash happens, it's at a seemingly random place in the application's main thread.

Has anyone else run into this issue? If so, what was the cause, and how did you fix it?

Disassembly of where the crash happens:

```
0x7fff8f2e1e3b:  leaq   98519(%rip), %rax         ; "Bug in libxpc: Domain environment context has overflowed maximum inline message size."
0x7fff8f2e1e42:  movq   %rax, -389938449(%rip)    ; gCRAnnotations + 8 
0x7fff8f2e1e49:  ud2    <--  crash
```

Backtrace from lldb:

```
* thread #4: tid = 0x122764, 0x00007fff8f2e1e49 libxpc.dylib`_xpc_domain_serialize + 496, queue = 'com.apple.root.default-overcommit-priority, stop reason = EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
frame #0: 0x00007fff8f2e1e49 libxpc.dylib`_xpc_domain_serialize + 496
frame #1: 0x00007fff8f2e18ca libxpc.dylib`_xpc_dictionary_serialize_apply + 84
frame #2: 0x00007fff8f2e1497 libxpc.dylib`_xpc_dictionary_apply_node_f + 105
frame #3: 0x00007fff8f2e16af libxpc.dylib`_xpc_dictionary_serialize + 161
frame #4: 0x00007fff8f2e1184 libxpc.dylib`_xpc_serializer_pack + 423
frame #5: 0x00007fff8f2e0f81 libxpc.dylib`_xpc_pipe_pack_message + 118
frame #6: 0x00007fff8f2e0985 libxpc.dylib`xpc_pipe_routine + 99
frame #7: 0x00007fff8f2dff2a libxpc.dylib`_xpc_runtime_init_once + 827
frame #8: 0x00007fff9076c2ad libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 8
frame #9: 0x00007fff9076c21c libdispatch.dylib`dispatch_once_f + 79
frame #10: 0x00007fff8f2e4144 libxpc.dylib`_xpc_connection_init + 64
frame #11: 0x00007fff8f2e40f6 libxpc.dylib`_xpc_connection_resume_init + 14
frame #12: 0x00007fff9076c2ad libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 8
frame #13: 0x00007fff9076e09e libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_root_queue_drain + 326
frame #14: 0x00007fff9076f193 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_worker_thread2 + 40
frame #15: 0x00007fff922f0ef8 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 314
frame #16: 0x00007fff922f3fb9 libsystem_pthread.dylib`start_wqthread + 13
```

---

Update with some more information:

I just found out something rather interesting.  This issue only happens when the application is launched by Xcode.  If I launch it via lldb on the command line, this crash does not occur.  Likewise, if I double click on it in Finder, the issue does not occur.

Comment: are those external libraries the latest versions?

Comment: No, but I've also tried the latest versions with no change in behavior.